# AzureDevOps YAML pipelines - Preventing malicious use of production service connection

Tags: security, azure-devops, yaml, azure-deployment, multistage-pipeline

I have created YAML pipeline & want to secure PROD service connection so that shouldn't be used in QA/UAT stages. I tried to add approvals on prod service connection along with PROD Environment approval(for PROD stage) but my pipeline fails immediately after approving Environment approval & throwing below error.

"##[error]The job is using protected resource(s) for which checks have not been evaluated endpoint:XXXXXX. For more details, refer to [https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks"](https://aka.ms/pipelinechecks%22)

Request you to please guide how I could fix it or achieve required control on PROD service connection. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your issue on my side. But all approvals should ask for review before the stage starts, you could only set approval for the service connection:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?